# Como checar se um arquivo já existe em um diretório do celular em Flutter?

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

Possuo um método para checar se determinados arquivos .pdf existem na pasta do app, usei path_provider para obter o caminho, como faço para checar se o arquivo existe no diretório?

```
Future<void> checkFile() async{

      try {

        var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

        path = "${dir.path}/${document["title"]}.pdf";

        if(path != null){ // Preciso checar aqui se o arquivo com exatamente este nome existe no diretório.

          setState(() {
            progressString = "Livro Baixado!";
          });

        }

      } catch (e) {
        setState(() {
          progressString = "Falha em checar se o livro já foi baixado!";
        });
        print(e);
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importei o dart:io e usei essa condição:

```
if( FileSystemEntity.typeSync(path) != FileSystemEntityType.notFound)
```

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar se existe ou não um arquivo no armazenamento local interno do aplicativo, use:

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
// para um arquivo
io.File(await path).exists();
// para um diretório
io.Directory(await path).exists();
```